# Какой из двух вариантов подзаголовка лучше (звучит)?

Tags: стилистика

1. Добрый доктор Dai Monet вам поможет, спору нет.
2. Добрый доктор Deneg Dai вам поможет, так и знай.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Второй вариант никуда не годится, поскольку "так и знай" - форма предостережения или выговора; к тому же, нельзя обратиться к кому-то одновременно на "ты" и на "вы" (вам + знай).
В первом варианте - грамматически неоправданное применение латиницы, если это не название фирмы, а имя доктора. К тому же, приходится несколько раз прочитать, чтобы догадаться, что здесь приделана рифма (поначалу Monet читается как "Моне", будто это китайский родственник французского художника).

Comment: Добрый доктор Deneg Dai всем поможет, так и знай. Так должно быть: это я поторопился. А предостережение, действительно, в какой-то мере присутствует:отстояв очередь и заплатив 50 у.е. за прием, ничего не получил, кроме пространных рекомендаций..Применение латиницы оправдано: врач, действительно был китайцем, а происходило это в Куала-Лумпуре, столице Малайзии.  И, все-таки, какой вариант лучше (с учетом сказанного)?

Comment: Если ирония оправдана ("выздоравливают как мухи" по Гоголю), то такой вариант неплох. Но латиница в написании имени остаётся спорной: даже в случаях, когда нужно точно воспроизвести имя на языке оригинала, в научных текстах его дают в скобках или в сносках. Разве что как шутливую условность можно оставить.

Comment: В моем тексте много слов, написанный латинскими буквами - это, в чаcтности малазийские и тайские названия, которые сложнопереводимы (воспроизводимы). А как насчет такого варианта "Добрый доктор Dai Mo Net вам поможет, спору нет"?

Comment: Тоже неплохо, даже близко к китайскому, хотя в нём и нет слога 'net' :)

Answer (score 0):

> Какой из двух вариантов подзаголовка лучше?

Оба хуже.

Ирония не доходит, латиница не оправдано, использование "говорящих имен" совершенно не воспринимается.

И самое главное. У подзаголовка (газетного, как я понимаю) есть только одна задача. Своей броскостью завлечь читателя прочитать заметку. Заметку с такой мудреной завлекалочкой я буду читать только по обязанности или с большой скуки.

Comment: Статья с таким подзаголовком вышла давно и все уже об этом забыли. Мой вариант был исправлен редактором. То, что получилось в результате, мне не совсем не понравилось: "Добрый доктор вам поможет, спору нет". Сейчас, речь о книге на основе тех статей. Уже "завлекать" не обязательно.